# Can you update an Android app with a completly different APK?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I have an app (App1) and it is released and being used. I have made a major update, but originally wanted it to be a new app, so I made another app (App2) in my developer console and began testing there.

I have changed my mind about it being a new app though. I want to update the original App1. I should have just done this in the first place. If I try and upload the App2 apk to App1 I get errors about the signature. Is it possible to copy the signature from App1 to App2 so that I can use the App2 apk to update App1?

Comment: But in that case your App2 package name is different then App1 package name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the same package name and signing key for both you shouldnt have any problems.

Dont forget to increment the versionCode and the versionName in your build.gradle file or manifest according to your last version, or you will have trouble after uploading it to the playstore.

Comment: Thanks. Is that the .jks file?

Comment: Yes and you should also use the same .keystore file for signing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the following:

- The package name should be same as it was before.
- increase the `versionCode` and `versionCode` as required.
- you need to use the same **release keystore** as before.

---

For your **app2** to you should also prepare an update which just simply opens the Google Play Store page of **app1** and notify the user:
 ***"This version is no longer supported please go to app1 download page"***.